# Ensure referential integrity when deleting domain entities referenced by primary key/id

Tags: java, c#, entity, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to design my web app with ddd practices in mind.
This app deals with the storage of containers in storage locations. A container contains a substance. Most likely, users will search for a substance and want to know in which location to find the container. Moreover, they will want to inventorize a storage location, i.e. get all containers of that storage location.

This is why I have identified substance, container and storageLocation as aggregates. I have learned, that other aggregates should not be referenced directly, but by primary key. Now, I am wondering what the best way to ensure referential integrity in my domain layer is (i.e. not having references that point to a nonexistent/wrong container), e.g. when deleting containers since substance and storageLocation have references to containers. Let's assume all references are bidirectional.
I am mostly afraid of "forgetting" to add appropriate methods to an entity which might be added later in the project. I am not sure if that even is a "valid" concern when programming.

These are my entities:

```java
@Entity
public class Substance{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    List<Long> ContainerIds;

    public void addContainer(Container c){containerIds.add(c.getId())}
    public void removeContainer(Container c){// removes c.getId() from list}
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Container{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id; //+get

    private Long substanceId; //+ get set
    private Long storageLocationId; //+ get set
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class StorageLocation{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Long> containerIds;

    public void addContainer(Container c){containerIds.add(c.getId())}
    public void removeContainer(Container c){// removes c.getId() from list}
}
```

Now, I'n my controller, I have to get the Substance and StorageLocation entities from the repository, remove the container ID references from them and then remove the container:

```java
public class Acontroller{

    private ContainerRepository containerRepository; // constructor injected
    private SubstanceRepository substanceRepository; // constructor injected
    private storageLocRepository storageLocRepository; // constructor injected

    public void deleteContainer(Container c){
        Substance sub =  substanceRepository.getByID(c.getSubstanceId());
        sub.removeContainer(c);

        //The same for the storageLocation

        containerRepository.removeContainer(c);
    }
}
```

And everytime I add another entityReference to Container, I will have to expand the controller method.

Is this way of managing the references "by hand" acceptable. If not, how would I go about doing it while retaining the reference by id? Or should I forget about the id and just work with object references?

---

ps: first SO question, so please be gentle with me and let me know what to change about the question.

Comment: Re: your ps, SO works best for specific questions. This *may* be a better fit for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @EcoRI There is no one-size-fits-all answer to this - your options largely depend on the problem domain. Are you sure `Substances` and `StorageLocations` can float around without a `Container` ? Is there a lot of concurrent access on `Container`, `Substance` or `StorageLocation`, and should a user be able to delete a `Container` without affecting others working on its related entities ? Do your entities have real behavior or are they just bags of data ? etc. All of this must be explored with a domain expert first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Only Model Necessary Associations

> Let's assume all references are bidirectional.

I think this is probably the first assumption you need to question.  When modelling your domain entities, it's best to think about the operations that they participate in and the invariants you need to enforce during those operations.  If bidirectional references aren't required for those operations and invariants, don't maintain them.

e.g. in your case - depending on your domain and invariants, you might be able to get away with uni-directional interfaces - e.g. perhaps `substance` holds a `containerId` and `container` holds a `storageLocationId`

Chapter 5 "Model Expressed in Software" of [Eric Evan's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) has an excellent discussion on this topic, including explicit debunking of the usual first-case assumption that references must be bidirectional.

### Is "Delete" a Business Operation?

Expanding on @VoiceOfUnreason's answer and Udi Dahan's blog, it is really important to understand what your users mean when they ask to be able to delete something. In your case - a few questions to ask:

- Has the container gone out of service?
- Will it return to service at some point in the future?
- Is it now being used in a different part of the facility?
- Is it being deleted because the container identifier has changed (e.g. a barcode has rubbed off and a new one printed and stuck on) - in which case you might be modelling the identity of the entity incorrectly, as the container is the same, but the barcode has been changed - in which case the barcode is not truly the container's identity
- What happens to substances in a container when it is 'deleted'? Have they been used? moved to another container?

### 'Referential Integrity' via Eventual Consistency

Sometimes things that look like invariants, are not really things that absolutely, positively, must at all times be enforced.  e.g. in the unlikely case that if you did discover through all of the above questioning that you really do need to delete a container, what would happen if there was a slight delay in processing the ramifications of the delete from the perspectives of the substances?

Could you publish a domain event `ContainerDeleted` and in the handler for that event, identify all the associated substances and do what needs doing to them? e.g. mark them as 'uncontained' or whatever makes sense in your domain.

This allows you to keep aggregates small by focussing on the things that truly are invariants for that aggregate - Vaughn Vernon's [Effective Aggregate Design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/) is great reading for exploring this concept.

### Identifying Hidden concepts in the Model

Sometimes through analysis and 'knowledge crunching' you can identify hidden concepts in the model, that when brought to light and modelled explicitly can simplify your model and business processes.  e.g. in your case, a few things that might be useful:

- Explicitly model a `ContainerPlacement`:

  - This could be a entity within the storageLocation aggregate - the stoageLocation may hold a collection of `ContainerPlacement`
  - `ContainerPlacement` could just hold a reference to a containerId and perhaps any properties required to enforce the invariants that the storageLocation must maintain - e.g. perhaps it holds a copy of the container volume valueobject to permit enforcing the invariant, "don't put more containers in me than will fit in me" on the storageLocation aggregate, whilst leaving most of the other properties of the container (e.g. colour, in-service date, etc.) as the responsibility of the container aggregate.
- What is a `substance` really? Can multiple containers contain the same substance? i.e. if substance is 'water' can multiple containers contain water? Is there a difference between the water in one container and the water in another?

  - Perhaps there is a difference between `substance` as an entity - maintaining the name of the substance and other properties of it - viscosity, density etc., and `substance` as a valuobject - representing the volume or quantity of the substance within a container.
  - this would simplify the model, as then the container would just have a ValueObject - perhaps called `ContainedSubstance` - on it defining a substanceId and a volume.  If containers can have multiple substances in them, you could model it as a collection of such valueobjects.

### Separating Query Operations

Some of your requirements are really query requirements - the domain model does not exist to satisfy query requirements - only to enforce invariants under changes.

You might find that even with the association modelling revealed by the above questions you can satisfy your queries with a relational database persistence of your domain model - but if not, you can also look into maintaining a separate [read model](http://cqrs.nu/tutorial/cs/03-read-models) to facilitate the queries whilst leaving your domain models purpose built to maintain their invariants.

Comment: I've now taken the time to remodel my 'delete' logic, which made me realize that the delete operation I wanted to perform was not in the domain model but rather concerned the underlying database rows... I accepted your answer since it expands further on @VoiceOfUnreason's points and I hope it will make people with a similar problem read both answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Udi Dahan: [Don't Delete -- Just Don't](http://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/)

> This app deals with the storage of containers in storage locations. A container contains a substance. Most likely, users will search for a substance and want to know in which location to find the container. Moreover, they will want to inventorize a storage location, i.e. get all containers of that storage location.
>
> This is why I have identified substance, container and storageLocation as aggregates.

So that's problem #2.  The motivation of aggregates is the protection of your business invariant.  Each aggregate is responsible for verifying any proposed change.  Analyzing queries doesn't tell you anything about change, so it doesn't tell you anything about where you can put the boundaries.

Problem #1 is that you appear to be modeling inventory, and the real world, rather than the model, is the "book of record" -- you can't remove a real container from a real store room by invoking a "delete" method.  If you contrast a model for an online shopping cart (Amazon?) with a model for a grocery shopping application, you can see the difference: click delete as many times as you like, the cereal box does not jump out of your cart.

But to address the question that you asked; if entity X has to satisfy an invariant that requires the existence of entity Y, then either X and Y must be part of the same aggregate (which can immediately reject any proposed change that would violate the invariant) or you have to relax the invariant and allow the model to eventually reconcile the conflict between X's state and the no longer available Y.